# Possible to prepopulate an inline entity form multiple with a url parameter?

Tags: 7, entities

Is is possible to add multiple entries into an inline entity form field with url parameters

I am able to populate almost any other field with the prepopulate module, just having difficulty with the IEF.

Scenario:

I have two content types of quote, and sales order. each of which has an entity reference of inventory (another content type) which has IEF as its widget.

I want to be able to create a sales order off of the quote, and bring over all the values of the entity reference field to the quote. The issue is i want to maintain the data on the quote, but be able to edit the "same" data on the sales order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with [Entity reference autofill](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autofill) and [Entityreference prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate) Modules.

1. Add an entity reference field in your entityform.
2. The entity reference autofill will automatically fill reference value into field. We can load default value from URL. (`?field_name = value`)
3. Entityreference prepopulate will prepopulate the values. (you have to add existing fields for that.)

For more details please refer project page.

Another approach is,

> If you want to do this by coding, Just pass **nid** through url and use [node_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load/7) to load that node and [create an entity form submission](https://www.drupal.org/node/2005160). If you want to create entity form with node creation use [hook_node_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) or [hook_node_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7).

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Both good suggestions.

I'm leaning towards the module route, thank you.

Question on the first suggestion, just curious. Will the values that are brought over from the source, be changed if they are modified on the destination side? Hopefully I am making sense.

Comment: Upto my knowledge changes in destination wont reflect in source.

Comment: I just wanted to let you and anyone else know that might be curious. The autofill module you suggested works as intended. If you modify a value in the new destination it will not modify on the source. Cool stuff.